# Why can't take Annotation on a Field together with getField() and setField()?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Example A will throw Exception as below, but Example B will be successful.

Why can't take Annotation on a Field together with `getField()` and `setField()`?
A `POJO` should have field, `get()`, `set()`.

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "wodogName"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String wodog.pojo.Wodog.getWodogName()
        at wodog.pojo.Wodog
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String wodog.pojo.Wodog.wodogName
        at wodog.pojo.Wodog
```

Example A:

```
@XmlElement(name = "WodogName")
private String wodogName;

public String getWodogName() {
    return wodogName;
}

public void setWodogName(String wodogName) {
    this.wodogName = wodogName;
}
```

Example B:

```
@XmlElement(name = "WodogName")
private String wodogName;

public void setWodogName(String wodogName) {
    this.wodogName = wodogName;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to annotate your class with [`@XmlAccessorType(FIELD)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessorType.html) to instruct JAXB to use annotations specified on fields.